# Routing function Express.js and retriving data from json

Tags: node.js, json, express

I have a problem with a routing function in express.

I call from firebase realtime database , the JSON has a lot of nested data and I would like to retrieve it with a for loop.

```
router.get('/admin_tavoli',  async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var lista_tavoli = await firebase().ref('tavoli').once('value');
        var lista_tavoli_val = lista_tavoli.val();
        for(var i in lista_tavoli_val){
            console.log(lista_tavoli_val[i].comanda.tavolo);
        }
        res.send('ok');
        } catch (err) {
         res.json({ message: err })
        }
   });
```

If I keep to the first level to JSON for example

```
for(var i in lista_tavoli_val){
      console.log(lista_tavoli_val[i].comanda);
     }
```

there are no problems.
But if I go deeper to JSON

```
for(var i in lista_tavoli_val){
      console.log(lista_tavoli_val[i].comanda.tavolo);
     }
```

the execution of the program goes in error, but the strange thing is that in the terminal I see the correct data.
Why does this happen?
thanks to all for the help

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Is run catch (err) {
         res.json({ message: err })
        }

Comment: but what does `err` equal?

Comment: the type of error is not specified

Comment: in the browser appears {"message":{}}